# @Id, @JoinColumn and others annotations when mapping a view

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

Here's my problem : i have two databases, with one containing tables that i will need in the second one. These tables are lists for many-to-one relationships, so they won't be updated frequently, but it's still a possibility.

So in order to not duplicate my tables i wanted to use a foreign data wrapper, create foreign tables that map them, and then create views that map these foreign tables. I want these views because i need to set specific privileges depending on the role of the user (something you can't do with foreign tables right ? You can only set an owner ?)

Anyway, now i have my views, and now i created Java classes so that Hibernate can map the tables.

My questions :

1/ **Is it bad practice** to use @Id @JoinColumn on classes that are mapping views ? Because they don't have primary or foreign keys. Will it end in **lack of performances** ?

2/ Am i completly missing something, and maybe there is **another database design** that could solve my problem ? Knowing that i can't merge my two datables and create two separate schemas.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: 1. No, hibernate works with views just like with tables, except you can only read from views. 2. I don't know as I don't really understand what you currently have

Comment: Well if there is no problem with 1. then i don't have a problem with my database design :) I was just wondering if Hibernate would have trouble to create relationships between my classes if he couldn't find any primary or foreign keys in my database

Comment: Hibernate doesn't care about the actual constraints ("at all"). You don't need foreign keys declared in your database and you can still join to other tables with ease

Comment: Ok good ! Thanks :)